# Is there a way to pull a report from salesforce using the sfdx command?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to pull some report already on salesforce.
Is there a way to pull it using the sfdx cli.
I've tried `sfdx force:source:retrieve` but it only retrieves the metadata not the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

The out-of-the-box sfdx CLI doesn't have a way to run reports. However, you could write your own plugin by using the [Salesforce CLI Plug-in Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_architecture_sf_cli.htm) or try to find an existing plug-in on NPM or Github. Also, you can run SOQL queries and get data out in several formats, including JSON and CSV. You can also use the [SFDX Data Move Utility](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility) for even better data handling capability.